# Why am i getting 'numpy.float64' object is not callable while passing X and y input in KNN regressor model in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, error-handling, regression, knn

**And will this KNN classifier class work for Regression Problem?**

Please can someone help me in this problem.

```
def most_common(lst):
    return max(set(lst), key=lst.count)

def euclidean(point, data):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum((point - data)**2, axis=1))


class KNeighborsClassifier:
    def __init__(self, X, y, k=5, dist_metric = euclidean):
        self.X = X
        self.y = y
        self.k = k
        self.dist_metric = dist_metric
     
    #Split the dataset to train and test subsets
    def trainTestSplit(self):
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(self.X, self.y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 0)
        return X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test

    def fit(self, X_train, y_train):
        self.X_train, self.X_test, self.y_train, self.y_test = self.trainTestSplit()
        
    def predict(self, X_test):
        neighbors = []
        for x in X_test:
            distances = self.dist_metric(x, self.X_train)
            y_sorted = [y for _, y in sorted(zip(distances, self.y_train))]
            neighbors.append(y_sorted[:self.k])
        return list(map(most_common, neighbors))
    
    def evaluate(self, X_test, y_test):
        y_pred = self.predict(X_test)
        accuracy = sum(y_pred == y_test) / len(y_test)
        return accuracy
    

# Preprocess data
ss = StandardScaler().fit(dataset.values[:, 0: -1])
X_train, X_test = ss.transform(dataset.values[:, 0: -1]), ss.transform(Model_KNN.X_test)

#KNN
Model_KNN = KNeighborsClassifier(dataset.values[:, 0: -1], 
                              dataset.values[:, -1], 
                              k=5, 
                              dist_metric = euclidean)

Model_KNN.fit(dataset.values[:, 0: -1], dataset.values[:, -1])
actual = Model_KNN.y_test
predicted = Model_KNN.predict(Model_KNN.X_test)

#predicted
Model_KNN_SSE = np.sum((predicted - actual)**2)
Model_KNN_RMSE = math.sqrt(Model_KNN/actual.shape[0])

print("SSE score KNN on Data = ", Model_KNN_SSE)
print("RMSE score KNN on Data  = ", Model_KNN_RMSE)
```

I am trying to define KNN Regressor class and input my dataset but I am stuck with the error mentioned below:

/var/folders/h0/tm1gdm4s34j097dtf8f7nj440000gn/T/ipykernel_87163/2979561256.py in

```
         11 Model_KNN.fit(dataset.values[:, 0: -1], dataset.values[:, -1])
         12 actual = Model_KNN.y_test
--->     13 predicted = Model_KNN.predict(Model_KNN.X_test)
         14 
         15 #predicted
```

/var/folders/h0/tm1gdm4s34j097dtf8f7nj440000gn/T/ipykernel_87163/2359822982.py in predict(self, X_test)

```
    39             y_sorted = [y for _, y in sorted(zip(distances, self.y_train))]
     40             neighbors.append(y_sorted[:self.k])
---> 41         return list(map(most_common, neighbors))
     42 
     43     def evaluate(self, X_test, y_test):
```

/var/folders/h0/tm1gdm4s34j097dtf8f7nj440000gn/T/ipykernel_87163/2359822982.py in most_common(lst)

```
      1 def most_common(lst):
----> 2     return max(set(lst), key=lst.count)
      3 
      4 def euclidean(point, data):
      5 # Euclidean distance between points a & data
```

**TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable**

Thank you so much in Advance!

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question and add the whole error traceback message.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I have added the traceback error message. Can you check and let me know where I am making a mistake? Thank you so much once again!

Comment: At some point you must have declared a variable named `max` or `set`, which replaced the built-in function of the same name.